# How to create a mvc project with vc# code in controller rather than vb code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I recently learn how to user VS2013, and I try to create a MVC project and automatically generate codes based on a database. but I found all codes in controller folder are VB not VC#. Please tell me is there a way to change them each other?

Project folder pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHcKK.png

Comment: while creating new project you should select visual c# template on left side  and select web applications

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new MVC-Visual C# project  and not a VB project (`Templates/Visual C#/Web`): [image]project